# local and NIS user with the same name - chown

Tags: linux, unix, chmod, chown, nis

I have a linux with a configured NIS domain, and both a local user and a NIS user with the name johndoe (but different UIDs).

When applying 'chown johndoe:johndoegrp somefile.txt' - which john doe will become the owner ?
I know I can see for myself with 'ls -n', but some end users told me that they got inconsistent outcomes.

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to check the order in /etc/nsswitch.conf. On Machine I have

```
  passwd:     files nis
```